# Question about scales and z-scores

Tags: scales

I have 1000+ evaluations of 65 students by faculty.  Two different eval forms, each evaluating the student in 5 areas, but 2 different scales:  1 a 3-pt scale; the other a 4-point scale.I'm thinking that to make the final report card for each student, I'll need to standardize the scores received on each form, from multiple faculty evaluators.  At a loss as to how to do so....can anyone help?   THanks!